# rxjava when timeout skip item and go on next item

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have 3 items. when an item run time out I want to skip then item and go on next item

I use a timeout or throttleWithTimeout. it's unuseful

```
 Observable<String> just = ReplaySubject.just("1", "2", "3");
        just
                .doOnNext( a -> {
                    if("2".equals(a)){
                      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                    }
                      System.out.println(a);
                })
                .timeout(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .onErrorResumeNext(o -> {
                    System.out.println("on error");
                }).subscribe();
```

console log:

```
1
on error
2
```

how can I implement timeout item skip, and go on next item.
I expect Output is :

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Observable<String> just = ReplaySubject.just("1", "2", "3");
just
        .flatMap(aa -> Observable.just(aa)
                    .doOnNext(a -> {
                        System.out.println(a);
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                    })
                    .timeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.empty())
        )
        .subscribe();
```

There is timeout for each item, thats why there is `flatMap`. With `flatMap` you can also control how many elements are processed concurrently  with `maxConcurrency` param. `Observable.empty` indicates that it will do nothing when timeout occurs.